# Data Not Going Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not sure why but in my image upload script none of my data is being entered into the database. This is the same script I've been using, but I recently added to `if(isset))` statements to see if certain checkboxs were checked. The images are being uploaded to the server, but the database table remains empty. Any clues? I'm not getting any errors.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $count = count($_FILES['img_file']['name']);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
        $img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
        $img_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $img_name);
        $img_album = $_POST['img_album'];
        $img_album = str_replace(' ', '_', $img_album);
        $img_photographer = $_POST['img_photographer'];
        $img_location = $_POST['img_location'];
        if(isset($_POST['horror'])) { $horror = "1"; } else { $horror = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['occult'])) { $occult = "1"; } else { $occult = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['goth'])) { $goth = "1"; } else { $goth = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['industrial'])) { $industrial = "1"; } else { $industrial = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['fashion'])) { $fashion = "1"; } else { $fashion = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['fetish'])) { $fetish = "1"; } else { $fetish = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['avante-garde'])) { $avanteGarde = "1"; } else { $avanteGarde = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['cosplay'])) { $cosplay = "1"; } else { $cosplay = "0"; }
        if(isset($_POST['nude'])) { $nude = "1"; } else { $nude = "0"; }
        $file_name = $_FILES["img_file"]["name"][$i];
        $file_ext = end((explode(".", $file_name)));
        $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/";
        $img_rename = $img_name . '_' . $i . '.' . $file_ext;
        $target = $target . $img_rename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target)){
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery_img (img_name, img_album, img_photographer, img_location, horror, occult, goth, industrial, fashion, fetish, avante-garde, cosplay, nude, file_location) VALUES ('$img_name', '$img_album', '$img_photographer', '$img_location', '$horror', '$occult', '$goth', '$industrial', '$fashion', '$fetish', '$avanteGarde', '$cosplay', '$nude', '$img_rename')") ;
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success margin-top">Image "'.$file_name.'" successfully uploaded and renamed to '.$img_rename.'.</div>';
        }else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your images.</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check for errors in your code. That's why you don't know what your error is.

Comment: The site has error checking enabled and I've ran it through syntax checkers. No errors.

Comment: neither of which will show a mysqli error  `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: What @JohnConde and @nogad are correctly saying is you have no idea if your insert worked.  This line -> `mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO ....`

Comment: You should use parameterized queries, you are open to SQL injections. Also `$_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES["img_file"]["name"]` are the only arrays?

Comment: For finding out what's wrong I'd suggest two things: (1) assign the insert-statement to a variable and echo it; then copy-pase the echo output, have a look at it, and try it directly in the database; (2) use the result of `mysqli_query`, which returns `FALSE` on failure, and probably explore `$mysqli->error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously weren't checking for errors in your query.

Notice the hyphen for one of your columns? It seems that others may have not scrolled over to the right (enough) to see it and to inform you about it.

- `avante-garde`

MySQL is interpreting that as:

- `avante` **minus** `garde` and thinking you wanted to do math. It should either be renamed using an underscore as you did for some of your other columns, or wrap it with ticks.

I.e.:

```
`avante-garde`
```

Btw, (and I'm not criticizing); that word is actually spelled ["avant-garde"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avant-garde), so make sure it is in fact that actual name. In either case, it would have failed you.

- **Note:** I'm really hoping that that wasn't a typo on your part and that you are/were using an underscore after all.

Using error checking on the query in a conditional statement would have helped.

I.e. and assign a variable to it:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery_img (...) VALUES (...)");
```

then

```
if($query){
  echo "Success";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Another thing. Make sure the column types are correct and of the right length. MySQL can fail silently if the lengths aren't long enough to accommodate the data.

Do use a prepared statement; your code is presently open to an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Footnotes:**

You may want to look into using a ternary operator instead of some/all those `if{...} else{...}` statements, plus it's a lot shorter code.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Example from the manual:

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

Of course, you can replace `empty` with `isset`.

---

**There is something worth noting** and that could (also) prevent your query from executing, and that is its location for the query.

You have it inside the following condition. If your upload fails, so will the query.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target)){
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery_img (...) VALUES (...)");
    echo '<div class="...">Success...</div>';
}else {
    echo '<div class="...">Error...</div>';
}
```

A few possible reasons why the upload failed, and could be one of any of the following:

- File(s) is(are) too large
- Permissions are not set for the folder to write to.
- Typo(s) for the file(s) inputs(s)
- Other

Reference for upload error codes/messages:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Ah. I failed to realize it would be interpreted as such. That's why my others were `avanteGarde` instead. I caught on to it there but failed to where you pointed out. Working like a charm now. Thanks for the other pointers. This script is still in development so I am definitely going to do some alterations with your tips. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @JesseElser You're most welcome Jesse, glad to have been of help; *cheers*

Comment: @JesseElser An added note about hyphens. That also applies to variables in php. I.e.: `$a-b` - Php would also intepret that as a mathematical operation; keep that in mind ;-)